# Automatically update Maven dependencies after JAR deployment

Tags: java, maven, deployment, dependencies, version

I have a Java Maven project with some dependencies defined in the POM.xml file.
These dependencies often have newer versions every month, so I would like to deploy a JAR file that automatically checks the latest versions of those dependencies in each startup (without re-building the Java Maven project).

Is it possible to achieve that with Maven?

I know that the [Versions Maven Plugin](http://mojo.codehaus.org/versions-maven-plugin/) is useful to download the latest versions of dependencies, but only when "re-building" the project (not in a deployed JAR). I also know that I can use expressions like:

```
<version>[1.8,]</version>
```

But, again, these dependencies are only downloaded after building the project. I want to update dependencies automatically every time the user launches the application.

**UPDATE:**

The dependency I want to automatically be updated is "selenium-chrome-driver". My application uses Chrome Driver to launch the Google Chrome browser.

The problem is that Chrome Driver is updated every few months, and the older versions become "outdated". As a result, after a few months, the deployed JAR tries to launch the browser with an older version of Chrome Driver and it doesn't work. For that reason, I need to automatically update this dependency. Otherwise, I would have to deploy a new JAR every X months.

Comment: Doing this is very dangerous.  You have no guarantee that an API change in a dependent library won't break your deployed code.  Something like this would be a software quality nightmare.

Comment: I agree, this would break your code once new versions are release and not compatible with existing code. Better update manually as needed.

Comment: I know, but otherwise I would have to deploy a new JAR every month. The problem is that this dependency is "selenium-chrome-driver". If I don't update Chrome Driver dependency, I can't launch the browser because after a few months a new driver appears and the JAR's driver becomes "outdated" and it doesn't work.

Comment: So work on build/deployment automation to make deploying a new version of your JAR very easy.

Comment: I agree that this is a solution, but I'm not sure that users will agree to download every X months a new JAR. In any case, I would like to know if Maven allows to automatically update dependencies in a deployed JAR.

Comment: You are married to the idea that Maven has to do this for you (which means you'll have to hardwire maven into your application), but in essence what you're asking is how to build an application which can auto-update certain libraries itself; with or without Maven. Perhaps if you drop Maven from your requirements, you can find something that already exists or design something yourself.

Answer (score 0):

I had same problem for years, there is a library to do this, https://github.com/bonigarcia/webdrivermanager , but I didn't try it myself

Currently am using this [script](https://gist.github.com/Amr1977/fa3ba0e33ba1a333c20cf3c047ef1b48) (ubuntu)

```
# https://gist.github.com/ziadoz/3e8ab7e944d02fe872c3454d17af31a5
# https://gist.github.com/birdsarah/23312f1d7cbd687ac376c95662254773

# This script checks & downloads latest chromeDriver and geckoDriver IF needed.
# New drivers are extracted and copied to $driversDestination
# IMPORTANT: Remember to change $driversDestination variable below to match your case
# You can call this script before launching your test suite so you always get latest drivers each run

os=linux64
driversDestination=../dependencies/browser-drivers/

if [ -e chromedriver_last.txt ]
then
    chromedriver_last_download=`cat chromedriver_last.txt`
fi

chromedriver_latest_version=`curl -sS chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com/LATEST_RELEASE`
if [ "$chromedriver_last_download" = "$chromedriver_latest_version" ]; then
    echo "Already has last chrovedriver version" $chromedriver_latest_version
else
    echo "Updating chromedriver from " $chromedriver_last_download "to" $chromedriver_latest_version
    wget -N http://chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com/$chromedriver_latest_version/chromedriver_$os.zip -O chromedriver_linux64.zip
    echo "$chromedriver_latest_version" > "chromedriver_last.txt"
    unzip -o chromedriver_$os.zip -d $driversDestination
    rm chromedriver_$os.zip
fi

if [ -e geckodriver_last.txt ]
then
    geckodriver_last_download=`cat geckodriver_last.txt`
fi

geckodriver_latest_version=`curl -s https://api.github.com/repos/mozilla/geckodriver/releases/latest | jq -r ".tag_name"`

if [ "$geckodriver_last_download" = "$geckodriver_latest_version" ]; then
    echo "Already has last geckodriver version" $geckodriver_latest_version
else
    echo "Updating geckodriver from " $geckodriver_last_download "to" $geckodriver_latest_version
    wget https://github.com/mozilla/geckodriver/releases/download/$geckodriver_latest_version/geckodriver-$geckodriver_latest_version-$os.tar.gz -O geckodriver.tar.gz
    echo "$geckodriver_latest_version" > "geckodriver_last.txt"
    tar -xvzf geckodriver.tar.gz
    rm geckodriver.tar.gz
    chmod +x geckodriver
    mv geckodriver $driversDestination
fi
```