# Maven dependency jar update needs update to dependent API

Tags: java, maven, dependencies, dependency-management

Our project uses a common library and this library is referenced in pom file of all API that use it. Now we have more than 50 API's.

Any change to the library leads to update in library version and has to be updated in all API's pom files.

Is there a better approach, where we can have a central reference to which all API's refer too and updating the library version there, takes care of every API.

And we want the version to be selective, the one we maintain in some file to be part of the build for all Api's not the latest, as it might be a beta and might cause instability. So unless someone updates the api version in some central reference, build process of the API's w.r.t that jar should remain unaffected.

I went through this link here but not much help [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23497066/automatically-update-maven-dependencies-after-jar-deployment)

Please suggest.

Answer (score 0):

If change needs to be propagated to all APIs, keep the version of the common library same and don't change APIs. For this, you can use SNAPSHOT concept. The difference between a "real" version and a snapshot version is that snapshots might get updates. That means that downloading 1.0-SNAPSHOT today might give a different file than downloading it yesterday or tomorrow.

But if you don't want to propagate changes to all APIs, then release a new version of the common library. Then update has to happen only in that API which depends on these new changes in the common library. Other APIs can continue to refer to the old versions.

On another note, if this common library is not doing a lot of heavy lifting, you could also consider its elimination. That might break DRY principle, but could also make things simpler by allowing APIs to be self sufficient.

Comment: 1). if we use, 1.0-SNAPSHOT for the jar and add it to our artifactory, I am not sure it will allow us to update the same file in the artifacotry repo. it maintains the versioning that way. Any new jar change will be allowed only with new version.  2) Also whenever we have to change it from snapshot to proper version, at that time the update will be inevitable.

Comment: If code is changed and version in pom is not changed, then the version would still be same with the changes.

Comment: what I mean is , i code is changed, we have to add the updated code in artifactory and while doing so, we have to update the version there, or it wont accept the new jar in same location in artifactory repo. like in maven repositories you will see diff jars with diff versions. so update to code leads to update to version and in turn update to pom.

Comment: I will stick to my answer as yours seem to be a process related issue to me. Please accept/upvote if it helped